# Html parse for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, parsing, windows-phone-8.1

I'm doing a Silverlight project for Windows Phone 8.1 and i really can't understand how to parse a single web page. My code is this:

```
var html = @"My Web SIte Url";
//It works if the html var contains the actual code and not the url
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
//If i use this line, i get an error on new HtmlWeb() 
var htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(html);
if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
{
    // Handle any parse errors as required
}
else
{
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        //I'm trying to get the first link for now
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode aNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
        if (aNode != null)
        {
            string first = aNode.GetAttributeValue("title", "null");
            string value = aNode.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(first);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.WriteLine(aNode.OuterHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

If I use `htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);`, I can get it work only if I have the html code inside `html`. If I use `var htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(html);`, I get the error that says that I'm missing a using statement. Can you help me please?

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a using statement. Which is kind of what the error was telling you in the first place.

Try

```
new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb().Load(html);
```

or add

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

on the top of your class with other references.